# Optimize speed of query which compares values of two different time-stamps

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=61b5d0582a53bdf9bd69ed4ef18d0e02)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO operations
(time_stamp, product)
VALUES 
("2020-01-01", "Product_A"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_B"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_C"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_D"),

("2020-03-15", "Product_A"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_C"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_E");
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
time_stamp,
product,

 (CASE 
 WHEN MAX(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY product) 
    = MIN(time_stamp) OVER () THEN 'deleted'
 WHEN MIN(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY product) 
    = MAX(time_stamp) OVER () THEN 'new'
 ELSE 'both' END) AS existing_type
 
FROM operations
GROUP BY time_stamp, product
ORDER BY product, time_stamp;
```

---

Wit the above query I check in the table if a product exists in `both` `time-stamps`. 
If it exists only in one of them it either gets assigned `deleted` or `new` to it. 
The query works fast and perfectly in the example.

However, when I apply it to my original database with much more data it performs very slow. 
Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to optimize the query to make it run fast also on a bigger amount of data?

Comment: Do you have only 2 timestamp values in your big table?

Comment: Please add a few more rows -- to include some "both" cases.  And also indicate the "correct" resultset.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have duplicate `timestamp`/`product` pairs in the data you have provided.  That suggests that the aggregation is superfluous:

```
SELECT time_stamp, product,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY product) = MIN(time_stamp) OVER () THEN 'deleted'
             WHEN MIN(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY product) = MAX(time_stamp) OVER () THEN 'new'
             ELSE 'both'
        END) AS existing_type 
FROM operations
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```